# HMR not working with Laravel Mix in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server, laravel-mix

I am having some problems setting up Hot Module Reloading in Laravel Mix inside a Docker container.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.0-fpm

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    nano apt-utils curl unzip default-mysql-client nodejs build-essential git \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmcrypt-dev libmagickwand-dev \
    libwebp-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev libaio-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev && \
    echo 'umask 002' >> /root/.bashrc  && \
    apt-get clean

# Docker PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv gettext gd mysqli curl pdo pdo_mysql zip && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-configure curl --with-curl

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Which I am building using the below docker-compose.yml file.

```
  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./webroot:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

In previous Node.js apps, I have copied over the data inside the dockerfile, and mounted the volume in the compose file, however this doesn't seem to be having the same effect with Laravel.

I am seeing the below output in Git Bash, however the web pages are not reloading with changes at all after I run npm run hot inside the container, not even with a manual refresh:

[image]

Despite this, npm run watch-poll, which I have used previously, still works as expected.

Typically I see logs in the console from HMR and WDS inside the browser when viewing the application. However in this situation I am not seeing any outputs.

Below I have also included my webpack.mix.js file. I have been messing around with some of the options, such as the port and host, as I know they need to be configured a certain way when running inside a container. Any help would be appreciated as I am struggling to work out where I am going wrong.

```
mix.options({
    hmrOptions: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '80'
    },
});

mix.webpackConfig({
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 80
    },
});
```

Edit:

Error output when running npm run hot after setting both host values to web:

```
> @ hot /var/www/html
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 172.25.0.4:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1292:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1496:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -99,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '172.25.0.4',
  port: 80
}
```

Comment: There is no log, it fails silently?

Comment: @loic.lopez Yea pretty much, do you know if there are any logs which could pinpoint a cause?

Comment: I think you might be interested with: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/868

Comment: Or maybe [Docker + Vue Hot Reload + Laravel + XDebug + PhpStorm](https://medium.com/@sam_ngu/docker-phpstorm-laravel-xdebug-vue-hot-reload-%EF%B8%8F-c561187e1bb9)

Comment: Unfortunately I have worked through both of those and they haven't really changed the output at all. Still no response inside them browser that HMR is active

Comment: you are running on a windows machine, right?

Comment: Yes I am running on a Windows machine

Answer (score 4):

the problem is in

```
mix.options({
    hmrOptions: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '80'
    },
});
```

you can not use localhost since it is refer to your APP container in this case, what should you do is using `web` instead since compose will resolve the service names for you:

```
mix.options({
    hmrOptions: {
        host: 'web',
        port: '80'
    },
});

mix.webpackConfig({
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        host: "web",
        port: 80
    },
});
```

Comment: Hello @LinPy, now I am getting the following errors on all of my resource files: http://web//css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout) etc...

Comment: is your web server running? what is in the web container logs ?

Comment: They just appear to be the standard logs you would expect: 172.25.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2020:08:52:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost/admin/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I can't even execute npm run hot now, just getting an error output. I have edited it into my main post, just doing a bit of research into the error myself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and used following command to fix that:

Laravel Mix version 6:

```
npx mix watch --hot -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --watch-options-poll=1000
```

The only issue is that change host and port by mix.options API, did not works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack might have issue with file watcher being inside docker. Try adding polling option in the devServer config.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  }
});
```

For the `listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 172.25.0.4:80` issue:

1. See if there's a container running with `docker ps`
2. Kill the blocking container with `docker stop [container_id]`

Comment: Still no luck, and there are no other containers running on that address. I only get it when I set both hosts to web like in @LinPy's suggestion, however otherwise is doesn't work anyway.

Comment: trust yourself, webpacker is not "might" but absolutely have bugs in Docker-windows for watching files change. this cost me half a day.